# Javascript path in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, plugins

I need to include a plugin javascript stored in folder `app/assets/plugins/`
In application.html.erb:

```
<script> var plugin_path = "<%= Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "plugins") %>";</script>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'script' %>
```

In script.js:

```
loadScript(plugin_path + '/pluginA/js/pluginA.js', function() {

    Init(false);

});
```

When I start my server and load my homepage, terminal displays a message like

> [GET] cannot find route
>   '/home/myapp/app/assets/plugins/pluginA/js/pluginA.js'

This url is correct (I suppose). So what is the problem here and how to load this plugin in a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

The heart of this issue is that `/home/myapp/app/assets/plugins/pluginA/js/pluginA.js` is not a URL.  It's a filesystem path. Your web browser currently believes that's a route in your Rails app (you should be able to verify a 404 in your development.log for your Rails app for that path.

The easiest fix may be to use `file:///home/myapp/app/assets/plugins/pluginA/js/pluginA.js` which *is* a URL.  You may wish to try that during development.

There is no chance this will work as you move this work to staging or production, where the site will be accessed by other web browsers.  You will need to learn how to integrate this plugin into the [Rails asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).  (It looks like requiring your script in application.js, and initializing it near the bottom of that file may be appropriate, but this is difficult to say without more knowledge.)